# Tangents of two concentric ellipses

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, plane-geometry

> Suppose a tangent to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ cuts the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{c^2}+\frac{y^2}{d^2}=1$ at points $P,Q$, and that the tangents to the second ellipse at $P,Q$ are perpendicular. Determine $\frac{a^2}{c^2}+\frac{b^2}{d^2}.$

I tried as: I take a point on inner ellipse and from that wrote the equation of tangent and then tried to find the intersection points to other ellipse . But this became too complicated.

Can anyone please give me how to proceed?

Comment: Please use Mathjax to express symbolic formulae.

Comment: Mathjax aside, it is entirely unclear what your question is asking. Please edit the problem statement for clarity.

Comment: @Semiclassical sorry , now I have edited it

Comment: I took a stab at editing the problem statement. Feel free to edit yourself if the revised problem statement isn't accurate.

Comment: @Semiclassical can you please help me out in this

Answer (score 2):

Try to prove first, then exploit, the following lemma:

> Given the ellipse $E_1$ with equation
>   $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, the locus of points $P$ such that
>   the tangents to $E_1$ drawn through $P$ are perpendicular is a circle
>   centered at the origin with radius $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Additionally, if
>   $P_1,P_2$ are the tangency points of the tangents from $P$, the
>   envelope of the $P_1 P_2$ lines is an ellipse $E_2$ concentric and
>   confocal with respect to $E$.

[image]

Comment: Can you show me the calculations

Comment: @koolman: it is way more instructive if you think about the given lemma and perform the computation by yourself. To learn mathematics is much more than putting the right symbols in the right place. I do not think that stating "the answer is one" really adds something to your knowledge or understanding.

Comment: Based on my (abortive) attempts at this question, I came up with another one which you might find interesting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918247/locus-of-intersection-of-two-perpendicular-normals-to-an-ellipse. (Instead of tracking the point $P$, track the point $P'$ such that $PP_1P'P_2$ would be a rectangle.)